# Two different datatype in function return

Tags: java, types, return

In this function I need two different datatype for return, one float when `y` is not zero and a Boolean when it's zero.

```java
public XXXXX division(int x, int y){
    if(y!=0){
        return x/y;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know that I can implement this with using two function 1- check correction of division 2- calculate the correct division what I want it in One function, It's possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing 0 as divisor shouldn't be allowed. You should throw an exception instead of returning false in this case:

```
public float division(int x, int y) {
    if (y != 0) {
        return ((float) x) / y;
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("division by 0 makes no sense");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure if it is a good practice to have a single method for something like that. But you can create your own class with result and error as property and then return object of that class from your method.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the value of `Y` is zero or not before calling the function itself. Don't allow zero to be passed to that function.

And anyway if you pass zero to the function divide by zero situation will throw `ArithmaticException`. So your function can throw that exception to the caller.

```
public float division(int x, int y) throws Exception {   ///ArithmaticException
    return ((float) x) / y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a Double as a return type and return the value normally. In case of false, return null.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way-

```
public Object division(int x, int y) {
    if (y != 0) {
        return x / y;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: x / y should be (double)x / y.

Comment: What about the result that will be returned how to interpret that ?

Comment: The calling code has to take care about that. Just to check for the type / instance of returned object.

Answer (score 1):

You could return `Float`, using `null` signify "no result":

```
public Float division(int x, int y) {
    if(y != 0) {
        return x / (float)y;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That said, in this particular case it might actually make sense to return IEEE infinity or NaN.

Note that I've fixed the integer division as it sounds that this isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check it prior:

Pseudocode

`if(y!=0){`

get `division(x/y)`

`}else{`

say `Cannot divide by 0`

}